# How to retrieve data from firebase database without DataSnapshot? #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This my database in firebase

[image]

I want to get the value of page which is equal to 200.

When I tried like that:

```
DatabaseReference my= userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 1").child("Page");

    System.out.println(my);
```

Output:

```
https://my-proje-book-timer.firebaseio.com/qpPLvgpM0TMF6vz4Kqw8QaYroG83/Books/Book%201/Page
```

When I tried like that:

```
DatabaseReference my= userid_database.child("Books").child("Book 1").child("Page").getKey();

    System.out.println(my);
```

Output:

```
Page
```

I don't want to use this:

```
 my.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Because I want to get all values for each Book pages and make a calculation with these values. In this way, I couldn't get the values outside of the method.

Comment: the nature of firebase interactions like this (and many other types of interactions you'll encounter when developing android apps) is that results are returned asynchronously.....so you will need to use `addValueEventListener` (or similar)

Comment: making a rest call to the url + ".json" will retrieve the data

Comment: [Off-topic] I'm here because I saw this question on the Firebase video by Frank Van Puffeler :D Who else is with me?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a listener, you can use [the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start) to easily make an HTTP query to find the data you want, assuming that it's readable without authentication.  If you need authentication, it gets more difficult.

But you're really better off just learning now to make the listeners work for you, even if you're not accustomed to that kind of processing.